# send a message to self in netty

Tags: netty

I want dispatch a job to netty's thread, if I don't do so, I have to care thread synchronization because the job was not triggered by message received from client side.
I found ChannelPipeline has a method sendUpstream meets my requirements, but I can not get all ChannelPipeline's object. I mean:

```
// code in thread which not belong to netty's thread
for(all pipeline)
    pipeline.sendUpstream(my_pseudo_message)

MyChannelHander.messageReceive() {
    //code to deal with my_pseudo_message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute something in the Worker-Thread of Netty use:

```
channel.getPipeline().execute(new Runnable() {...});
```

Comment: What if I use OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor? It still run in I/O thread? That's not I want...

Comment: channel.getPipeline().execute(..) always put your work in the I/O Thread

Comment: Any way dispatch it to given channel's ChildExecutor if I use OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: so you want "just" make sure its gets executed in the same Executor as everything else for a given channel when using OMATPE.. right ?

Comment: yes. I want make sure there is no synchronization problem (I/O thread might can't see data changes in OMATPE) and I don't want this job be executed concurrency with this channel's normal message process. My business domain object has not consider synchronization.